# place div based on the scrollposition

Tags: jquery

I got a floating header div that follows my scroll position. my problem is when im lets say half way down the site and do a jquery post and that post it returns a partial view of the floating header div, that gone place it in its original position wich is at the top of the site. i want to bring it back based on my scroll position (scrollTop?).

i tried some different ideas i had but did not succed with it so i thought i would post the question here.

this is what i tried and got now.

my floating div is called `#float-header`

```
$('#float-header').animate({ scrollTop: 430 //static value just for testing });

$('#float-header').scrollTop($('html, body').scrollTop());

$('#float-header').top($('html, body').scrollTop());
```

any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at `position:fixed` it is supported by IE7+ and all other common browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this option worked good, i just forgot to add the class that was needed for it to float.

```
$('#float-header').addClass('float-it');
$('#float-header').scrollTop($('html, body').scrollTop());
```